# Firebase messaging on the local time

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I faced with the issue using firebase cloud messaging. In case if I send message on some local time everything works perfectly, but the messages which scheduled on "Recipient time zone" not working at all.

[image]

I have disable swizzling in plist `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled = NO` and handle receiving of push message by myself.

```
func userNotificationCenter(
    _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
    didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void
) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

    completionHandler()
}
```

Do you have any ideas what possibly can be wrong? Because all others messages from FCM working fine. I have issue only when use recipient time zone.

Comment: I have the same issue - with the addition of _any_ scheduled notification doesn't send. Only "now" notifications created with the Firebase wizard will actually send to my test devices... *Following this